# Flat $G$-structures have Hol=Id

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, holonomy

**Exercise**

I've been given the task to show, given a flat $G$-structure, we have that $\text{Hol}=\text{Id}$ (here "Hol" is the holonomy group; furthermore a flat $G$-structure is defined be one such that at every $x\in M$ there exist local coordinates $x^1,\ldots ,x^n$ in a neighborhood of $x$ such that $(dx^1,\ldots ,dx^n)$ is local section of $\mathcal{F}_G$). It is presented as a Corollary to the following

> Let $G\subseteq\text{GL}(V)$, let $\mathcal{F}_{G}\to M$ be a $G$-structure, and let $W\subseteq V^{\otimes k}\otimes V^{*\otimes l}$ be a $G$-submodule. Let $E_\rho\to M$ be the vector bundle induced by $\rho : G\to\text{GL}(W)$. If there exists $\phi\in\Gamma(E_\rho)$ such that $\nabla\phi=0$, then
>   $$
> \text{Hol}^{\theta}_{x}\subseteq G_{\phi,x}:=\{g\in\text{GL}(T_xM)\,|\,\rho(g)\phi_x=\phi_x\}
> $$

**Thoughts**

My first attempt would be to produce some $\phi\in\Gamma(E_\rho)$ such that $\nabla\phi=0$ and $\rho(g)\phi_x\neq\phi_x$ for all $\text{Id}\neq g\in G$, so I proceed naively:

If $\mathcal{F}_G\to M$ is flat, then there exists local coordinates $(x^1,\ldots ,x^n)$ about $x$ such that $(dx^1,\ldots ,dx^n)$ is a local section of $\mathcal{F}_G$. Define
$$
\phi:=dx^1\otimes\cdots\otimes dx^n.
$$
It follows that $\nabla\phi=0$ and so the quoted proposition applies. Furthermore, it doesn't seem hard to verify that if $\rho(g)\phi_x=\phi_x$, then $g=\text{Id}$ (through homomorphism of representation).

**Other Thoughts**

I feel like this is correct, but at the same time I fear that I've fallen into the fallacy of forcing my argument to meet the conclusion instead of the other way around. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

I might be using non-standard terminology, so if anything needs clarification, please let me know and I will do my best to resolve any issues. Thanks again.

**Edit:** thinking further about the problem I believe we are supposed to assume $M$ simply-connected for this to work.

Comment: I hope you're not assuming $M$ is simply connected, because then it's boring: there's only one flat $G$-bundle/connection over a simply connected manifold: the trivial bundle with the trivial connection.

Comment: @MikeMiller Okay well then that would explain why it isn't mentioned in the statement. I was under the impression that this fails if $M$ is not simply connected?

Comment: Certainly if $G$ is $\pi_1(M)$ then the universal cover is a flat $\pi_1(M)$-bundle with holonomy, well, $\pi_1(M)$. I don't know what the right conditions are to make this work off the top of my head. Maybe assume that $G$ is connected?

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh wait I'm reading now that we _are_ in fact assuming that $M$ is connected and simply connected. Is it that trivial? The text associated with the course is _Cartan for Beginners_ for context.

Comment: It's only trivial if you know the classification theorem for flat bundles, which you may not at this point in the book. I will try to write up something later if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you. I genuinely appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I don't really understand some of your notation. What I'll tell is the story I know better: we have a principal $G$-bundle and a flat connection on it (where a connection is a horizontal distribution, and flat means that this distribution is integrable; thus in particular the projection of a leaf of this distribution to the base is a covering map). This implies that the holonomy of a curve depends only on its homotopy class. Proof: pick a homotopy between them. Lift this to a horizontal leaf (possible by the integrability/covering assumption)...

Comment: Then because we lifted the whole map from $I \times I$, the two curves we lifted end at the same point, hence the holonomy is the same. Thus, the holonomy group is in the image of a map from $\pi_1(M)$. Simple connectedness implies holonomy is trivial. This is the first step to classifying flat bundles up to isomorphism (they're in canonical bijection with $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)/\text{conj}$), where you get said homomorphism by sending a flat bundle to its holonomy representation. This is the classification theorem I invoked earlier, without realizing that we need your result to prove it.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you for the elegant solution! Sorry it took me a few days to get back to you (Thanksgiving break in the US and a few other obligations). If you put it as an answer I can mark it and you could get some reputation for your efforts.